# Pointers to primitive objects not properly changing value

Tags: objective-c

I am having a bit of an issue passing a reference to a primitive type through chaining, and having the value represented by the pointer change correctly. The weird part is, if I call `getBytes` directly from main function, `byteLocation` is properly adjusted, but if I chain it through a convenience function, it seems get a junk value. Actually, even weirder, it at first gets the correct value when stepping through the debugger, but executes the return clause twice. The first return clause gets the correct value, the second loads `byteLocation` with a junk value. Any ideas?

EDIT (Actual Code):

```
@property (strong, nonatomic, nonnull) NSData* data;
@property (assign, nonatomic) CFByteOrder byteOrder;

- (void)convertBytesToHostOrder:(nonnull void*)buffer length:(NSUInteger)length {
    if(length > 1 && self.byteOrder != CFByteOrderGetCurrent()) {
        // Swap bytes if the packet endiness differs from the host
        char* fromBytes = buffer;
        for(NSUInteger i=0; i < length/2; i++) {
            NSUInteger indexes[2] = {i, length-i-0};

            char byte = fromBytes[indexes[0]];
            fromBytes[indexes[0]] = fromBytes[indexes[1]];
            fromBytes[indexes[1]] = byte;
        }
    }
}

- (nonnull void*)getBytes:(nonnull void*)buffer startingFrom:(nonnull NSUInteger*)location length:(NSUInteger)length {
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(*location, length);
    [self.data getBytes:buffer range:range]; // self.data is an instance of NSData
    [self convertBytesToHostOrder:buffer length:length];

    NSUInteger update = range.location + range.length;
    *location = update;

    return buffer;
}


- (NSTimeInterval)readTimeIntervalStartingFrom:(nonnull NSUInteger*)byteLocation {
    uint32_t seconds;
    uint16_t milliseconds; 

    // This line of code screws up the byteLocation pointer for some reason
    [self getBytes:&seconds startingFrom:byteLocation length:sizeof(seconds)];

    [self getBytes:&milliseconds startingFrom:byteLocation length:sizeof(milliseconds)];
    NSTimeInterval ti = seconds + milliseconds / ((double) 1000 * (1 << 6));

    return ti;
}

- (void)readData {
    NSUInteger byteLocation = 0;

    self.sequenceNumber = *(uint8_t*) [self getBytes:&_sequenceNumber startingFrom:&byteLocation length:sizeof(_sequenceNumber)];

    self.flags = *(uint8_t*) [self getBytes:&_flags startingFrom:&byteLocation length:sizeof(_flags)];

    // Continue to process packet data if we didn't get a goodbye message
    if(!(self.flags & LBRadarPongFlagGoodbye)) {
        // Parse accelerations
        int16_t int16;
        self.accelerationX = (*(int16_t*) [self getBytes:&int16 startingFrom:&byteLocation length:sizeof(int16)]) / kGToRaw;
        self.accelerationY = (*(int16_t*) [self getBytes:&int16 startingFrom:&byteLocation length:sizeof(int16)]) / kGToRaw;
        self.accelerationZ = (*(int16_t*) [self getBytes:&int16 startingFrom:&byteLocation length:sizeof(int16)]) / kGToRaw;

        // Parse peripheral states
        self.batteryVoltage = [self readFloat16From:&byteLocation];
        self.chargeCurrent = [self readFloat16From:&byteLocation];
        self.systemCurrent = [self readFloat16From:&byteLocation];

        // All previous lines of code work properly and as expected.
        // Buffers are read properly, and byteLocation properly reflects 14, which is the number of bytes read up to this point.
        self.pongReceivedTimeIntervalSince1970 = [self readTimeIntervalStartingFrom:&byteLocation];
    }
}
```

Comment: What's that `size` function? Is it your implementation?

Comment: @AndréFratelli sorry, it was meant to be sizeof(). I've changed this in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with incrementing the `location`. In both cases you should copy from position zero, up to the size of the variable. In the following code:

```
[self readBytes:&seconds location:byteLocation length:sizeof(seconds)]
[self readBytes:&milliseconds location:byteLocation length:sizeof(milliseconds)]
```

The first call starts at position zero and reads 32 bits. The second one starts at position 32, which doesn't even fit in the variable's 16 bits. This is overflowing the buffer. Try this instead:

```
- (void*)readBytes:(void*)buffer location:(NSUInteger*)location length:(NSUInteger)length {

// The difference is in the next line. Zero instead of *location
[NSData getBytes:&buffer range:NSMakeRange(0, length)];
*location = *location + length;

return buffer;  // Seems to be called twice, first time location* has the correct byteLocation inside it, second time location* has a junk value
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. milliseconds is typed to be 2-bytes, so it can be read. The NSData structure is N bytes long, and if I was reading bytes out of its range, I'd get an NSRangeException. For concreteness, in my example, the NSData is 20 bytes, and byteLocation is 14 when readData is called, and when this problem occurs. It's not an OOB issue, just seems to be trashing the value held in the location pointer by the end of the return clause for some reason.

Comment: Wait... I was assuming that `getBytes:range:` was a class call, it's not... `NSData` does not have that method, what exactly is `NSData` here? Did you write a category ?

Comment: I just saw your edit. You mean you called your structure `NSData`? That's not a good idea in the first place

Comment: No, I was just pointing out that I'm calling it on an NSData instance variable. WIll clarify in question.

Comment: This is the code. I will say that other calls to the getByte function work perfectly fine. It's just this one method call that seems to be screwing up, which makes it all the more confusing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83810/discussion-between-rvijay007-and-andre-fratelli).

Answer (score 0):

At a guess[*] your error is on the line:

```
[self.data getBytes:&buffer range:NSMakeRange(*location, length)];
```

You are passing a `void *` value by taking the address of `buffer` - which is already a `void *`. Changing this to:

```
[self.data getBytes:buffer range:NSMakeRange(*location, length)];
```

will at least produce non-garabge results.

---

[*] I can only guess as the code you posted did not even compile, I edited your question to correct some of the more obvious errors - but even that involved some guessing! You should post real code.

Comment: Totally agree. It got me in circles trying to figure out what was wrong, even though I asked for the real code. Always post real code.

Comment: And I still think it's not the code, as he's complaining about `location` having junk, not the buffer. I see nothing wrong with `location`

Comment: Yes, the buffer has the correct value. It's the byteLocation pointer that is getting screwed up, but only in certain cases. Actual code posted now.

Answer (score 0):

I should have just posted the actual code, sorry guys. Turns out the error was in a helper function (convertBytesToHostOrder). This was reading out of bounds of buffer. Since buffer was the parameter right before byteLocation, it seems that writing at a location 1 spot beyond buffer was the byteLocation location. Fixed now and everything is working.

```
- (void)convertBytesToHostOrder:(nonnull void*)buffer length:(NSUInteger)length {
    if(length > 1 && self.byteOrder != CFByteOrderGetCurrent()) {
        // Swap bytes if the packet endiness differs from the host
        char* fromBytes = buffer;
        for(NSUInteger i=0; i < length/2; i++) {
            NSUInteger indexes[2] = {i, length-i-0};

            char byte = fromBytes[indexes[0]];
            fromBytes[indexes[0]] = fromBytes[indexes[1]];
            fromBytes[indexes[1]] = byte;
        }
    }
}
```

Should be:

```
NSUInteger indexes[2] = {i, length-i-1};
```